# Can I run no-parsed header scripts under Apache 2.2.9 without the nph- preface?

Tags: perl, apache

I have a basic Apache 2.2.9 setup under fedora core 8. I would like to set my own HTTP headers to come out (HTTP Forbidden / 403).

If I name the file nph-foo.pl, it works. If I name the file foo.pl, it fails and I get a server error, type 500.

According to all web references I've found, the nph-filename convention was no longer necessary effective in Apache 1.3 forward.

Is there a header / apache configuration directive I need to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you need a no-parsed-header script for this? Have you tried printing a "Status" CGI header?

```
print "Status: 403\n\n";
```